# Изменение весов фильтров в свёрточном слое нейронной сети

Tags: c#, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение

Начал изучать архитектуру работы свёрточных нейронных сетей. В процессе реализации столкнулся с проблемой изменения весов в фильтрах свёрточного слоя в случае работы с объёмами глубины, отличной от 1.

Для простоты рассматриваю следующую структуру слоёв:

```
    +-----------------------------------+
    |        Входное изображение        |
    |               HxWxD               |
    +-----------------------------------+
                       |
    +-----------------------------------+
    |          Свёрточный слой          |
    |                                   |
    |    вход: HxWxD, выход: H1xW1xD1   |
    |                                   |
    |     K фильтров размером FxFxD     |
    |  S сдвиг фильтров, P доп. нулями  |
    |    H1 = (H - F + 2P) / S + 1      |
    |    W1 = (W - F + 2P) / S + 1      |
    |              D1 = K               |
    +-----------------------------------+
                       |
    +-----------------------------------+
    |             ReLU слой             |
    |                                   |
    |  вход: H1xW1xD1, выход: H2xW2xD2  |
    |                                   |
    |     H2 = H1, W2 = W1, D2 = D1     |
    +-----------------------------------+
                       |
    +-----------------------------------+
    |          Maxpooling слой          |
    |                                   |
    |  вход: H2xW2xD2, выход: H3xW3xD3  |
    |                                   |
    |            scale [= 2]            |
    |          H3 = H2 / scale          |
    |          W3 = W2 / scale          |
    |              D3 = D2              |
    +-----------------------------------+
                       |
         [convert volume to vector]
         [W3xH3xD3 -> W3*H3*D3 = N]         
                       |
    +-----------------------------------+
    |        Full connected слой        |
    |                                   |
    |         вход: N, выход: M         |
    |                                   |
    |           W: matrix MxN           |
    |         activate: sigmoid         |
    +-----------------------------------+
                       |
```

Для ещё большего упрощения рассмотрим на примере RGB изображения, размером 32x32.

- Входной объём будет иметь размеры 32x32x3
- В свёрточном слое будем использовать K=4 фильтра размера 5x5x3, с S=1, P=0, то есть слой из объёма 32x32x3 получит объём 28x28x4 путём свёртки входного объёма с каждым из K фильтров.
- ReLU слой обнулит все отрицательные числа в объёме и вернёт его, так что на выходе вновь будет слой 28x28x4
- Maxpooling слой с множителем 2 превратит объём 28x28x4 в объём 14x14x4
- Полносвязный слой получит на вход вектор из 14*14*4 = 784 элементов, умножив который на матрицу W = [10x784] (будем распознавать 10 классов), получит вектор из 10 элементов со значениями от 0 до 1 (так как активирован сигмоидой).

После чего мы находим вектор ошибки e, который распространяем назад умножая транспонированную матрицу W на вектор e, и преобразуем его в объём 14x14x4 последовательным занесением аналогично преобразованию объёма в вектор.

Слой макспулинга вернём объём 28x28x4, в котором в немаксимальных элементах будут нули, а в элементах, где было максимальное значение будут соответствующие значения объёма 14x14x4.

Слой ReLU умножит каждый элемент на 1 или 0 в зависимости от того, положительное или отрицательное число получалось на выходе, и вернёт тот же слой 28x28x4.

И вот тут происходит проблема. Для получения изменения весов нужно выполнить свёртку входного объёма 32x32x3 с объёмом 28x28x4, при этом каким-то образом получив 4 объёма 5x5x3. Если предположить, что объём дельт разбивается на 4 объёма 28x28x1, но опять же, как получить 5x5x3, а не 5x5x1, чтобы изменить веса?

Ещё раз кратко: 
Forward: [32x32x3] => convolution with 4 filters [5x5x3] => [28x28x4] => ReLu => [28x28x4] => maxpooling => [14x14x4] => vectorize => [784] => W * X => [10]
Backward: [10] => W^T * e => [784] => 'volumize' => [14x14x4] => unpool => [28x28x4] => * relu grad => [28x28x4] => ???